# Create Matrix table using Pivot in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have table with dynamic TabHeader like:

```
RecordNum | TabHeader | tabvalue
1              A         data1
1              B         data2
1              C         data3
2              A         Data4
2              B         data5
2              c         data6
3              A         Data7
```

i want to create query table to achive :

```
   recordNum |   A      |  B    |  C  |
      1        data1     data2   data3
      2        data4     data5   data6
      3        data7
```

i tried using pivot but have no luck,
please guys any body can help me
query :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(tablecoloumnmap)

                    from temptes
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT recordnum ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select *
                from temptes
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(tablevalue)
                for tablecoloumnmap in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Just Made some correction to your existed sql script which will give exact result that you expected try it

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(TabHeader)

                    from temptes
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT recordnum ,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select *
                from temptes
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(tabvalue)
                for TabHeader in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
PRINT @query
execute(@query)
```

Result

```
Recordnum    A        B       C
----------------------------------
1           data1   data2   data3
2           Data4   data5   data6
3           Data7   NULL    NULL
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a game of "spot the difference". *Describe* what you've changed and why it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation instead :

```
select RecordNum, 
       max(case when tabheader = 'A' then tabvalue end) as A,
       max(case when tabheader = 'B' then tabvalue end) as B,
       max(case when tabheader = 'C' then tabvalue end) as C
from table t
group by RecordNum;
```

**EDIT :**  Here is Dynamic version of Pivot :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(TabHeader)
                      FROM temptes
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 1, ''
                    )


SET @query = N'select *
               from temptes x pivot 
               ( max(tabvalue)
                 for TabHeader in (' + @cols + ')
               ) p '

EXECUTE (@query)
```

Comment: oh i forget to tell that my tabheader are dymanic, so can not use hard code to it

Comment: @RioArfani. . . Then you should look into `Dynamic Pivot`.

Comment: yes i allready try that, but still no good result for me, can you help me sir

Comment: @RioArfani. . . Edit the question & add that query.

Comment: @RioArfani. . .  Your query should work with appropriate colum_name & table_name, i have used the column_name as per question.

Comment: can you share the query ?, i think i miss something but dont know what

Comment: the result are nothing like i want, but thanks for your effort @yoges Sharma

Comment: @RioArfani. . . What result you got, i got same as you provided.

Comment: recordnumber not distinct, and some null data not in the right place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183947/discussion-between-yogesh-sharma-and-rio-arfani).